# Loop in Python: Do stuff before first iteration

Tags: python, loops, optimization

I want to optimize.

## Simple solution

```
connection = get_db_connection()
for item in my_iterator:
    push_item_to_db(item, connection)
```

*Drawback:*

`get_db_connection()` is slow. If `my_iterator` is empty, then I want to avoid to call it.

## "if None" solution

```
connection = None
for item in my_iterator:
    if connection is None:
        connection = get_db_connection()
    push_item_to_db(item, connection)
```

*Drawback:*

If there are 100k items in `my_iterator`, then `if connection is None` gets called 100k times (although it is needed only once). I want to avoid this.

## Perfect solution ...

1. don't call `get_db_connection()` if iterator is empty
2. don't call `if connection is None:` uselessly for every iteration.

Any idea?

Comment: This is massive over-optimization. `if not i` is an insignificant overhead compared to whatever will happen in `push_item_to_db`.

Comment: If `get_db_connection` is slow, "optimizing" to avoid an `if` statement doesn't seem the right thing to do... That said, your iterator ought to throw a `StopIteration` that terminates the for each loop when it is empty.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes, this is "massive over-optimization". But nevertheless I like this question, since I have no clue how to solve it. For me it is more fun then a question which really "hurts" me.

Comment: Why do you need to enumerate?  in your snippet you don't use it.  Why not just interate over my_iterator?  Inside for loop, connect only if not yet connected by checking value of connection

Comment: @joelgoldstick yes, you are right. I changed enumerate() to "if None".

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like:

```
connection = None
for item in my_iterator:
    if connection is None:
        connection = get_db_connection()
    push_item_to_db(item, connection)
```

Simple solution. Don't need to overthink it. Even with 100k operations, `x is None` is just a reference comparison taking one Python opcode. You really don't need to optimise this compared to a full tcp roundtrip + disk write that happens on every insert.

Comment: Yes, your "if" is faster than mine. But I would like to avoid it nevertheless.

Comment: Then you'd have to go with @coredump's answer. That's pretty much the only way to avoid explicit `if`. Just keep in mind it's still not guaranteed to be an optimisation. It can actually be slower and I'd definitely prefer to review the a simpler solution if I was looking at your code.

Comment: you think there is no other solution?

Comment: What kind of solution are you looking for? You've got the loop over some collection and you need to start a db connection on the first element - there are many ways to write it, but it's essentially always going to be the same thing.

Comment: I search a solution does fit the above text: **Perfect solution ...** 1: don't call get_db_connection() if iterator is empty, 2: don't call "if connection is None:" uselessly for every iteration.

Comment: @guettli Is there anything wrong with my answer (not pythonic enough)? I am curious because it does behave as you describe.

Comment: @coredump Please look at *Perfect Solution*: 2. don't call `if connection is None`: uselessly for every iteration ... this "if" is only needed once.

Comment: @guettli Sorry I should have commented under [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36400263/124319). There I have only a while True loop and not unnecessary check.

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert in Python but I would do something like this:

```
def put_items_to_database (iterator):
    try:
        item = next(iterator)

        # We connect to the database only after we 
        # know there at least one element in the collection            
        connection = get_db_connection()

        while True:
            push_item_to_db(item, connection)
            item = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

It is probably true that the performance is tied to the database here. However the question is about finding a way to avoid doing unnecessary work, and the above is a basic  way of controlling precisely what happens during iteration.

Other solutions are "simpler", in some way, but on the other hand I think this one is more explicit and follows the principle of least astonishment.

Answer (score 2):

```
for item in my_iterator:
    # First item (if any)
    connection = get_db_connection()
    push_item_to_db(item, connection)
    for item in my_iterator:
        # Next items
        push_item_to_db(item, connection)
```

Comment: The only drawback is that is could be labelled as "too clever" by some people (for me it would be fine).

Comment: @coredump: the drawback that I see (in some other solutions as well) is that the  body of the loop needs to be duplicated.

Comment: Yes, I commented elsewhere about this but somehow did not notice that in your answer. Still, I prefer this one because it looks more straightforward.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: My solution 4 avoids duplicating the body of the loop, using 'itertools.chain()`.

Comment: @MikeMüller: we are working on a micro-micro-optimization (avoidance of an if test), and it is likely that any mechanism which is added (like try block or extra parameter in `next` call) adds more overhead than the if alone does. We cannot conclude without precise benchmarking, and most probably all this effort is totally worthless.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1

This works without a `while True` loop.

```
try:
    next(my_iterator)
    connection = get_db_connection()
    push_item_to_db(item, connection)
except StopIteration:
    pass
for item in my_iterator:
    push_item_to_db(item, connection)
```

## Solution 2

If you know that that iterator never returns `None` (or any other unique object), you could take advantage of the default of `next()`:

```
if next(my_iterator, None) is not None:
    connection = get_db_connection()
    push_item_to_db(item, connection)
for item in my_iterator:
    push_item_to_db(item, connection)
```

## Solution 3

If you cannot guaranty a value that never is returned by the iterator, you could use a sentinel.

```
sentinel = object()
if next(my_iterator, sentinel) is not sentinel:
    connection = get_db_connection()
    push_item_to_db(item, connection)
for item in my_iterator:
    push_item_to_db(item, connection)
```

## Solution 4

Using `itertools.chain()`:

```
from itertools import chain

for first_item in my_iterator:
    connection = get_db_connection()
    for item in chain([first_item], my_iterator):
        push_item_to_db(item, connection)
```

Comment: What's wrong with a "while True" loop? I am genuinely curious because you seem to prefer instead having two calls to "push_item_to_db" in all your solutions, which I don't find particularly nice.

Comment: Nothing really wrong.  I just prefer a `for` loop over a `while` loop if possible. "Feels" a bit nicer or more pythonic (maybe ;)).

Comment: Why do not you put the `for` statement in an `else` branch in solutions 1-3? That would avoid useless execution of the `for` when the iterator does not return anything.

Comment: The `else` would never get executed if the iterator has any members. The `else` would only be reached if the iterator is empty. Besides a `for` over an empty iterator does zero iterations.